# How to get the list of window handles and the window with the focus from a windows crash dump file?

Tags: windows, windbg, analysis, crash-dumps

I'm looking at a crash dump and would like to know the list of HWNDs and the HWND with keyboard focus. I tried a few types with `!handle` but I'm not getting any information. `!handle` is listing all types of handles but I don't see HWNDs being listed there.

What I mean by "HWND with keyboard focus" is that, I would like to find the HWND that [`GetFocus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646294(v=vs.85).aspx) will return.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: HWND is not that kind of kernel handle that !handle knows about.

Comment: Do you have a user mode dump or a kernel mode dump? Also note that this is a GDI handle, not a kernel handle.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Its user mode heap dump

Comment: That information is not stored in a user mode dump

Answer (score 1):

Most of the window manager is implemented in kernel mode so you probably need a full dump to get any useful information.

You could try the [0cchext](https://github.com/0cch/0cchext) extension but I don't know if it works on dumps, [SDbgExt](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=7) does not.

You could also disassemble `GetGUIThreadInfo` to see where it gets its data from...